# Add timestamp on video recording in android

Tags: android, text, camera

Hi i am new in android development. I am working on a camera application . I want to add timestamp on video while recording. Can any one help me for this. I don't want to use FFmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Countdown timer for this may help you to get timestamp of every seconds and then you can format and convert according to your need in minute hour or second.

Read about it
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer